# Count how many times is the same value present in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

After grouping in aggregation I have elements that look the following way:

```
{_id: ID, items: ["yes", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "yes", "no", "no", "no"]}
```

I'd like to project how many times is certain value present in items array

To end up with a document in the format of:

```
{_id: ID, yes: 3, no: 6}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a combination of **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** and **[`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)** operators to filter the items array based on a given condition and return the count respectively. For example, run the following pipeline to get the desired result. Of course this assumes the distinct binary elements from the items list `"yes"` and `"no"` are known beforehand:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "yes": {
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$items",
                        "as": "item",
                        "cond": {
                            "$eq": ["$$item", "yes"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "no": {
                "$size": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$items",
                        "as": "item",
                        "cond": {
                            "$eq": ["$$item", "no"]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

---

For a solution where the distinct elements are not known in advance, then you would need to **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** the items array, group the flattened documents and aggregate the counts as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$items" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$items",
            "id": { "$first": "$_id" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$id",
            "counts": {
                "$push": {
                    "item": "$_id",
                    "count": "$count"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

**Sample Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ID,
    "counts" : [ 
        {
            "item" : "yes",
            "count" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "item" : "no",
            "count" : 6
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add two more phase to your aggregation pipeline

```
{ $unwind: '$items' }
```

Then group by `items` again,

```
{ $group: { _id: '$items', count: { $sum: 1 }}}
```

This will generates an array like:

```
[{ _id: 'yes', count: 3}, { _id: 'no', count: 6}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([ 
  "$project" : {
    _id : 1,
    "yes" : {
      $size : {
        "$map" : {
          input : "$items",
          as : "Yes",
          in : {"$eq" : ["$$Yes","yes"]}
        }
      }
    }
    "no" : {
      "$size" : {          
        "$map" : {
          input : "$items",
          as : "No",
          in : {"$eq" : ["$$No","no"]}
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```